# Can't Get Dictionary For Loop to Pull Strings From the Correct Columns

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to create a dictionary from two columns in an Excel file. My code is as follows:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('country_data.xlsx')

sheet = wb["List of countries"]

for i in range(1, 198):
    list1 = list(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value)
    list2 = list(sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value)

dictionary = dict(zip(list1,list2))

print(dictionary)
```

I fixed my original error (forgot I didn't need to start my columns from zero) but now when I print my dictionary or lists, it seems like they each pulled in random values. I'm trying to pull in values from column 1 and column 3 of my excel file.

My columns look like this:

```
Col1      Col3
ger       Germany
eng       England
fra       France
spa       Spain
etc       etc
```

Yet, when I go to print my dictionary, it seems to have pulled random letters from unknown columns in my excel file and is only printing this:

{'z': 'a', 'w': 'f', 'e': 'r'}

How can I fix this error? I am trying to make column1 the key for my dictionary and column 3 my value.

Comment: You passed `column=0` to one of the calls. If this is 1-up counting, sure it should be `column=1`?

Comment: I changed the column value to 1 (forgot I didn't need to start from 0 this time), and now the code prints out values, but not from the columns I want, and only 3 values instead of the 198 values that are in each of the two columns I would like to add to my dictionary. (Column 1 = key, and Column 3 = value). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using `column=0`, however since it counts from 1, col 0 dosen't exist. Try this instead:

```
list1 = list(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value)
list2 = list(sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem! I had to create temp variables that equaled the sheet cells I was looking for within my for loop. After each one of those lines ran I then appended that temp variable to my list. Upon completion of the for loop, I zipped my dictionary, printed it, and everything was there.